# A better way to use onmouseover, onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

How I can better make an use of onmouseover, onmouseleave and onmousemove in this JSFiddle file? http://jsfiddle.net/Insane96MCP/xznn7g3d/5/

You can see that I have:

```
document.getElementById("button1").onmouseover = function(){
    showToolTip(/*...*/);
}
document.getElementById("button1").onmouseleave = function(){
    hideTooltip(/*...*/);
}
document.getElementById("button1").onmousemove = function(){
    showTooltip(/*...*/);
}
document.getElementById("button2").onmouseover = function(){
    showTooltip(/*...*/);
}
//And so on
```

There's a better way to do this, instead of stacking them in succession, creating a long javascript?

Comment: Try with classes instead of id's.

Comment: @NemanjaPopovic yeah, but I need a specific string for every element

Comment: You could use event delegation, [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dL4go89x/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array and for loop like

```
var ids = ['time', 'start', 'pause'];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(ids[i]).onmouseover = function(e) {
        showTooltip(Strings.timeTooltip, e);
    };

    document.getElementById(ids[i]).onmouseleave = function(e) {
        hideTooltip();
    };

    document.getElementById(ids[i]).onmousemove = function(e) {
        showTooltip(Strings.timeTooltip, e);
    };
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xznn7g3d/7/)

Comment: yeah, but i need to pass a string for every id: http://jsfiddle.net/Insane96MCP/xznn7g3d/8/ and doesn't work

Comment: @Insane96MCP, see http://jsfiddle.net/xznn7g3d/9/ it works now because you need to wrap it in IIFE because it is in a loop. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: @Insane96MCP, has this solved your problem? Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I'm from mobile now, I'll try when at home